# BST implementation

Tags: c++

My implementation of BST. Critique will be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class Node {

    template <class X>
    friend class BST;
    template <class X>
    friend void clear(Node<X> *root);
    template <class X>
    friend bool search(const Node<X> *root, const X x);
    template <class X>
    friend Node<X>* to_add(Node<X> *root, const X x);
    template <class X>
    friend std::ostream& preorder(std::ostream& ss, Node<X> *root);
    template <class X>
    friend std::ostream& postorder(std::ostream& ss, Node<X> *root); 

    T data;
    Node<T> *left;
    Node<T> *right;

    Node(): data(), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }
    Node(T dt): data(dt), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }

    T get() const { return data; }
};

template<class T>
void clear(Node<T> *root);

template <class T>
class BST {
    template <class X>
    friend void clear(Node<X>* root);
    template <class X>
    friend std::ostream& bst_preorder(std::ostream& ss, BST<X>& tree);
    template <class X>
    friend std::ostream& bst_postorder(std::ostream& ss, BST<X>& tree);

    Node<T> *root;

public:
    BST(): root(nullptr) { }
    BST(Node<T> *n): root(n) { }
    ~BST() {
        clear(root);
    }

    bool in_tree(T x) const;
    BST<T>& insert(T x);
};

template<class T>
void clear(Node<T>* root) {
    if (root) {
        if (root->left) {
            clear(root->left);
        }
        if (root->right) {
            clear(root->right);
        }
        delete root;
    }
}


template<class T>
bool search(const Node<T>* root, const T x) {
    if (root) {
        if (x == root->data) 
            return true;
        else if (x < root->data) 
            return search(root->left, x);
        else 
            return search(root->right, x);
    }

    else
        return false;
}

template<class T>
bool BST<T>::in_tree(const T x) const {
    return search(root, x);
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* to_add(Node<T> *root, const T x) {
    if (root->left == nullptr && root->data > x)
        return root;
    else if (root->right == nullptr && root->data < x)
        return root;
    else if (root->data > x)
        return to_add(root->left, x);
    else if (root->data < x)
        return to_add(root->right, x);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

template<class T>
BST<T>& BST<T>::insert(const T x) {
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(x);

    if (!root)
        root = temp;
    else {
        Node<T>* correct = to_add(root, x);
        if (correct) {
            if (correct->data > x)
                correct->left = temp;
            else 
                correct->right = temp;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& preorder(std::ostream& ss, Node<T>* root) {
    ss << root->data << " ";
    if (root->left) 
        preorder(ss, root->left);
    if (root->right)
        preorder(ss, root->right);

    return ss;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& bst_preorder(std::ostream& ss, BST<T>& tree) {
    if (tree.root) {
        return preorder(ss, tree.root);
    }

    return ss;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& postorder(std::ostream& ss, Node<T>* root) {
    if (root->left)
        postorder(ss, root->left);
    if (root->right)
        postorder(ss, root->right);

    ss << root->data << " ";

    return ss;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& bst_postorder(std::ostream&& ss, BST<T>& tree) {
    if (tree.root) {
        return postorder(ss, tree.root);
    }

    return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The main thing I can think of, is that anyone using the BST class, shouldn't have to know what a Node is.  The user should just be adding a value, searching for a value, etc.in the BST class.  With this in mind, I would suggest keeping the Node class a private member of BST, and all the functions, add,search, etc. should be members of BST.